# Problem with updating plain TeX, plain pdf-TeX, e-TeX, pdf e-TeX, and xetex formats

Tags: miktex-update

Updating plain TeX, plain pdf-TeX, e-TeX, pdf e-TeX, and xetex formats fails. Updating the other formats is possible only after excluding these formats. Do I need these formats if I use mainly pdfLaTeX or LaTeX2e?
 Error:

*

```
Creating the etex format file...
Running miktex-pdftex.exe...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6200) (INITEX)
entering extended mode
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/plain/config/etex.ini"
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
! I can't find file `hyphen'.
l.1222 \input hyphen           
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
l.1222 \input hyphen              
No pages of output.
Transcript written on etex.log.
Sorry, but miktex-makefmt did not succeed for the following reason:
  miktex-pdftex.exe failed on etex.ini.
```

*

Comment: You don't need the formats, but they shouldn't fail. Check if you have the "knuth-lib" package installed.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike! It doesn't fail after installing the "knuth-lib" package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.